# Какую литературу посоветуете для изучения PHP с нуля?

Tags: php, книги

Какую литературу посоветуете для изучения PHP с нуля?

Comment: мне одному показалось, что вопрос был задан про книги, а все отвечают про видеоуроки?

Посмотрите здесь - [Результаты запроса php][1]

[1]http://www.ozon.ru/?context=search&group=div_book&text=php

Answer (score 2):

Здравствуйте! Возможно вас заинтересует [данный сайт.](http://ru.html.net/tutorials/php/)
Мне, например, было очень легко я приятно читать эти небольшие уроки, которые дадут вам фундамент для дальнейшего самостоятельного изучения php.

Comment: Вот этот сайт очень понравился, спасибо большое. Остальные прочитаю после этого.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста :) Также на данном сайте вы найдёте книги по HTML и CSS. Всё доступно и понятно изложено.

Answer (score 0):

Книги не читай все переписано с документации php, Читай только и только Документацию (manual)! Вот ссылка на скачивание: [php_manual](https://www.php.net/get/php_enhanced_ru.chm/from/ru.php.net/mirror) А на счет литературы рекомендую
Профессиональное программирование на PHP (автор: Джордж Шлосснейгл, год: 2006) Книга хоть 2006 года но научить: использовать самые популярные шаблоны проектирование, кэширование, отладка, распределение приложения, производительность, профилирование, Расширяемость и конечно обработка ошибок!

Answer (score 0):

Из книг мне больше всего понравилась книга Николая Прохоренка "HTML, JavaScript, PHP и MySQL. Джентльменский набор Web-мастера"

Comment: сам учился по ней)

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5. Профессиональное программирование
Гутманс Э., Баккен С., Ретанс Д.

Answer (score -1):

на счёт литературы не знаю, но в нете можешь поискать вебинары Специалиста по php(4 части)

Answer (score -3):

Все Технические Моменты Онлайн Бизнеса в Видеоформате 2 или PHP+MySQL для начинающих

Евгений Попов. очень интересные уроки.

Comment: ни в коем случае! Попов учит быдлокоду